# Complex aggregation logic with getstream.io

Tags: getstream-io

I'm trying to see if getstream.io is the tool I need to build a feed architecture. I pretty much understood the building blocks, but I have some questions about aggregation.

Ideally, I would like my activities to be aggregated following two rules:

- Aggregated by day and actor first
- Aggregated by day and target as soon as the target **gets popular**

I don't see a proper way to do this for now, except inserting two different actions which will get aggregated differently. The problem is that when a single activity is added I will always get twice the same when reading the feed, so I need to filter them out at reading time if I want a clean feed. Is there a proper way to do this ?

Also, some additional questions:

- Is there a way to aggregate over a time window ? And not juste per time unit.
- If not, is there a way to aggregate over multiple days ? Probably, if the templating language supports operations on days, but is it the case ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like for your use case, you want to use two different aggregation formats. This might work better for you if you post the activities in different feeds with different aggregation formats (https://getstream.io/docs/#aggregated-feeds). You can also use TO targeting (https://getstream.io/docs/#targetting) to redirect activities to your clean feed. Hope this helps!